# How to return a specific SQLite row after a successful Image Tracking

Tags: android, image, sqlite

My issue is a totally specific one.

I use an Augmented Reality platform that implements Image Recognition through a smartphone camera.
I have stored at specific rows in my Android SQLite Table details regarding some photos I have stored in my phone.

And after my successful image tracking(I use image recognition for navigating purposes) I want to display those data on a xml archive according to my recognized image, but I can't come up with an idea how to do it.I haven't found so far some code similar to my problem.

How will I correspond my recognized image with each image specific data I have installed in my SQLite Table?

Comment: Could you try using metadata tags? i.e. if its a really red picture, the tag could be "red".
Not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: I use an Augmented Reality platform that implements Image Recognition through a smartphone camera.How will I correspond my recognized image with each image specific data I have installed in my SQLite Table?

Comment: Well I'm not exactly familiar with that particular software, but you could, one by one, compare the image from the camera to every image entry in the SQLite table until you find a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-->Problem solved.It works like a charm and retrieves a specific SQLite row<--

I inserted a method named getContact in DataBaseHandler.java to retrieve a specific row and I called it my MainActivity.

```
// ---retrieves a particular contact, written in DataBaseHandler---
    public Cursor getContact(String rowId) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_IMAGEID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_INFO }, KEY_IMAGEID + " LIKE '"
                + rowId + "'", null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mCursor.getCount() < 1) {
                Log.e("GetContact", "cursor empty for " + KEY_IMAGEID + "=\""
                        + rowId + "\"");

            }

        } else
            Log.e("GetContact", "cursor null");
        return mCursor;
    }
```

//Main Activity call of getContact method

```
public void DisplayContact(Cursor c) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Image_ID:" + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Title:" + c.getString(1)
                            + "\n" + "Info:" + c.getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

DataBaseHandler db;
        db = new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());// Your table is
                                                            // created now

        db.open();

        Cursor c = db.getContact("24");
        System.out.println("Cursor size " + c.getCount());
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            DisplayContact(c); // edo kalei ti methodo DisplayContact pou
                                // tiponei tin
                                // 2i grammi tou SQLite Table
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();
        }
```

My initial DataBaseHandler.java was:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


    public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "My_SQLite_Database.db";

    //constructor for this class
    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating the Table when the class is executed    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + "My_SQLite_Database" + "("
                + "Image_ID" + " TEXT,"
                + "Image" + " TEXT," + "Title" + " TEXT," + "Info" + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);//executing the create table query
    }

    //for inserting data into this table write the following method
      public void addData(String field1, String field2, String field3, String field4) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Image_ID", field1); 
        values.put("Image", field2); 
        values.put("Title", field3); 
        values.put("Info",  field4); 

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert("My_SQLite_Database", null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(DataBaseHandler.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "My_SQLite_Database");
            onCreate(db);
    }
}
```